# iOS Google Calendar book an appointment

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-calendar-api

Currently now i am working on **Google Calendar appointments**. Through google calendar we can create appointment slots. So i want to book these appointment slots through iOS application. I am doing research on this from past one day but through the application i found that we can create events and some other activities but i did not find any iOS tutorial regarding **creating an appointment slots, book an appointment slots** through Google Calendar api. Can any one please  provide any tutorial links, api links related to this.

Comment: Did you discover how to book an appointment via their API?

Answer (score -1):

Have you already tried this one? https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/ios